# Rnn prediction rate affected by batch size?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm using Tensorflow RNN to predict a bunch of sequences. I use Grucell and dynamic_rnn. While training, I input Training dataset, which I separate into `8` batches, each batch has batchsize of `10` (1 batch has shape of `[10, 6, 2]`, which is `[batchsize, seqlen, dim]`). And to prevent overfitting, I stop training when prediction rate in Training dataset starts to exceed 80% (usually stops at accuracy of 80%~83%).

After training, I let the same graph to just predict (not train) the same Training dataset. But this time, since tf.nn.dynamic_rnn makes it possible to feed batches of variable size, I can tailor the dataset into `80` batches, each batch has batchsize of `1`, and shape of `[1, 10, 2]` (simply lowered batchsize and therefore increased number of batches). Then, Accuracy usually exceeds 90%, which is appreciably higher than 80%. For some reason, Shrinking batchsize leads to higher accuracy rate. Why this happens?

Comment: My first intuition is that smaller batches may be easier to learn in the same amount of time. There is an issue with overfitting when you are learning sequences. Maybe it picked up more "features" of the sequences instead of learning the whole sequences.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have less amount of training data and you also early stopping during training, Don't stop blindly for handling overfitting check your training and validation loss difference if the difference is increasing that means your model is started overfitting. And before training check, your dataset is it biased or correctly balanced. I think this is happening because you have very less training data or your data set is not balanced.

Comment: I check validation loss, and about 80% is when the validation loss starts to increase. I have a small number of data (about slightly over a thousand), maybe this is the cause.